# Hooking for create window and want to get class name

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I am new to c++ and Hooking. For create window hooking i am using following code

```
static HRESULT WINAPI HookCreateWindowEx(
    __in      DWORD dwExStyle,
    __in_opt  LPCTSTR lpClassName,
    __in_opt  LPCTSTR lpWindowName,
    __in      DWORD dwStyle,
    __in      int x,
    __in      int y,
    __in      int nWidth,
    __in      int nHeight,
    __in_opt  HWND hWndParent,
    __in_opt  HMENU hMenu,
    __in_opt  HINSTANCE hInstance,
    __in_opt  LPVOID lpParam
    )
{
      return TrueCreateWindowEx(dwExStyle,lpClassName, lpWindowName, dwStyle, x, y,nWidth,nHeight,hWndParent,hMenu,hInstance,lpParam);
}
```

here i want know lpClassName It isn't giving correct name. How can i get correct name?

Comment: It would help if you described what class name you get and what class name you expect. The system seems to get along quite well, so the class name cannot be all that wrong. Also, hooking is usually the last resort. Depending on your requirements there may be better options.

Comment: I cannot find 'HookCreateWindowEx' on MSDN.

Comment: Also note: lpClassName may be class atom.

Comment: @MartinJames: Raj is likely using Detours or similar hooking library to replace `CreateWindowEx()` with his own `HookCreateWindowEx()` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to detect which windows are being created, you should create a DLL that [installs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) a global hook for `WH_CBT` / [`CBTProc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644977%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
g_hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, (HOOKPROC)CBTProc, g_hInstance, 0);
```

For each created window, `CBTProc` will be called with these arguments: `CBTProc(HCBT_CREATEWND, HWND hwndOfNewWindow, CBT_CREATEWND cbtCreateWnd)`.

So your `CBTProc` should look like this:

```
SUPPRESSDIALOGHOOK_API LRESULT CALLBACK CBTProc(__in  int nCode, __in  WPARAM wParam, __in  LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (nCode == HCBT_CREATEWND)
    {
        // wParam = handle to the new window
        // lParam = long pointer to a CBT_CREATEWND structure
        HWND hwnd = (HWND)wParam;
        CHAR name[1024] = {0};
        GetClassName(hwnd, name, sizeof(name));
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(g_hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Hi Wouter Huysentruit, Initially i have used this code http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/67091/Mouse-and-KeyBoard-Hooking-utility-with-VC but sometimes it is not hooking. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0bfcdb4e-1328-462c-bcc5-662f45b07b7e/what-is-required-to-get-a-whcbt-global-hook-to-work-on-windows-7 that why i am using **HookCreateWindowEx** instead of **SetWindowsHookEx** can you help me here

Comment: `HookCreateWindowEx` is not a valid Windows API function, says Dr. Google. But anyway that codeproject article should be a good start. First try to get that keyboard/mouse hook working **from a separate DLL**, then modify it and hook to `WM_CBT` as described in my answer.

Comment: Hi Wouter Huysentruit, what do you say about this [http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0bfcdb4e-1328-462c-bcc5-662f45b07b7e/what-is-required-to-get-a-whcbt-global-hook-to-work-on-windows-7]

Comment: Have tested CBT hook code I have here and it works on Win7 x64. Only thing is that if your hook DLL calls functions that need correct user rights, f.e. write to file, you have to make sure that every process you start has rights to write that file because the hook DLL will be injected in each started process.

Comment: It says SUPPRESSDIALOGHOOK_API is unknown identifier

Comment: Also says g_hHook, g_hInstance are unknown identifiers